# android Downoad Manager get STATUS_PENDING always

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I don't know why but I get always STATUS_PENDING even if file is downloading and it must be STATUS_RUNNING.

If use an recursive method with runnable with delay, after couple seconds again and again on the same id I got the right status. Any ideas?

The code for obtaining status is:

```
     public static void checkStatus(long downloadId) {
    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
    Cursor cursor = manager.query(query.setFilterById(downloadId));

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
        switch (status) {
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                Log.d("status", "STATUS_PENDING");
                //here you can set your TIMEOUT solution
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                Log.d("status", "STATUS_PAUSED");
                break;

            case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                Log.d("status", "STATUS_RUNNING");
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                Log.d("status", "STATUS_SUCCESSFUL");
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                Log.d("status", "STATUS_FAILED");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any solutions to this? See my related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882393/when-is-downloadmanager-ready-to-begin-downloading