# Android DownloadManager retry interval

Tags: android, cordova, android-download-manager

I would like to know the retry interval for `DownloadManager`.

My downloads get stuck at `STATUS_PAUSED` status, with the reason `PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY`. (This is strange because I have no connection problem and it only happens on Android 6 - please see [this separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882393/when-is-downloadmanager-ready-to-begin-downloading) for further info).

The app eventually retries to commence the download but the delay is way too long, and the interval seems irregular. When does `DownloadManager` attempt to retry the download? Is there a way to manually trigger the retry?

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of going about this is:

1. Keep track of the id returned on DownloadManager.enqueue
2. Check for status at intervals you desire and DownloadManager.remove if needed

Unfortunately, as far as I can recollect, the automatic retry cannot be triggered manually.

Hope this helps!